# Empty exception when converting inputstream to JSONArrary

Tags: java, android, json, wcf, arrays

I've an Android app that tries to consume a WCF service that returns a list of objects. The stream reads correctly, but throws an empty JSONException when trying to convert the string to a JSONArray. I checked the JSON response on a JSON validator and this seams OK.

My WCF Servicecontract:

```
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IAndroidWebService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "AndroidGetTenants",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<TenantEntity> AndroidGetTenants();
    }
```

The JSON response it generates when it is called:

```
[{"MaxVotesPerSecond":0,"Name":"Duurzaam OV","PartitionKey":"a63569b9-e794-4674-832b-46e85de0dc0a","RowKey":"02f1654c-9746-4da5-a146-bff7fe611468"},
    {"MaxVotesPerSecond":0,"Name":"Overheid","PartitionKey":"e38f3d93-5b4d-41e9-8513-3fd350a019af","RowKey":"11ec2c3e-e65f-45cf-9c89-4aa40a2c21c7"}]
```

The java code used in my app:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://XX.XX/WebService.svc/Android/AndroidGetTenants");        
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");        
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");  

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();        
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);       
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();         

byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];        
InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();  
stream.read(buffer);
stream.close();  
String tekst = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");                          
JSONArray tenants = new JSONArray(tekst);
```

The java code throws an empty JSONException (parameter e in the catch doesn't exists). It seems that the service returns an array of objects. 
When I change:

```
JSONArray tenants = new JSONArray(tekst);
```

with

```
JSONObject tenants = new JSONObject(tekst);
```

The code throws an `JSONException: Value [{"RowKey":"02f1654c-9746-4da5 ......  esPerSecond":0}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Which indicates to use the JSONArray, but that again throws the empty exception mentioned above.

Hope someone can help.

---

Extra information:
This code also throws the same Exception:

```
String tekst = "[\"1\",\"2\"]";                         
JSONArray tenants = new JSONArray(tekst);
```

This is a simple JSON array and I really don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Is that JSON what **should** come down from the server, or have you logged out the value of `tekst` before attempting to create the `JSONArray`?

Comment: It is the actual JSON that comes from the service. I think the code is correct, but that there is some kind of problem in my SDK. Completely reinstalled my system (including Windows 7), but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend that you change out all your stream monitoring code for the parser in the framework, so the response block would become:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);           
String tekst = EntityUtils.toString( response.getEntity() );
```

This might help guarantee you get all the correct data down from the server and properly formatted.  It may be something in the way your reader is pulling down the characters.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this gives the same JSONException.